# Css changes won't take effect

Tags: css, dreamweaver

So on the current website i'm working on, I can't make any changes to the css stylesheet on the page. When I try and make a change it works initially but as soon as I let go of the mouse it reverts back to what it was. It is like the stylesheets or locked or something. I would like to take some of the top padding of the title and change it's size but but it will not permanently change. Have a look at the website emmaanddavidswedding.com and you will see what I mean. I know for sure that it is my coding and not the dreamweaver program because I dont have this problem when working on other files/websites. If anyone can lend me a hand that would be great. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

**html**

```
<div class="title">
    <a class="title a href" href="http://www.emmaanddavidswedding.com">Emma & David's Wedding</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: alex-brush;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 363%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.title a href {
color: #ffffff;
}

.title a:hover {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: You have a number of typos etc - http://jsfiddle.net/qpoLsox2/

Answer (score 1):

The following is the issue here.

```
<a class="title a href">
```

You cannot have gaps in your class names. For  to work you need this in your CSS

```
.title.a.href {
}
```

I would advise against having a .a class name and .href class name.

Instead try

```
<a class="title">
```

and use

```
a.title { }
```

to target it

Comment: I have made those changes but unfortunately they have not worked. Then dreamweaver crashed and it didn't save the changes (its crashing frequently) . The thing is, I cant make any  changes to any css element on the page. Every time i try to make any change in just moves straight back to what it was before. It might be something to do with the link to my css file. Here is the link to the css: 


<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="index1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: OK, So try this.

1.Open your CSS document with a text editor (notepate on PC, Textedit on Mac)
2. Make a change to the CSS and save the file
3. Open the web page in your browser and you should see the change take place